# Running Python script with QProcess after freeze

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qprocess, fbs

I am using PyQt5 and freezing the app using fbs.
The app allows for users to run Python scripts. I then save the script in a Python file and run a QProcess to run that file.

The scripts that will be running are written by the user.
I want to be able to run scripts that import specific libraries like NumPy without having the user install the libraries themselves.

How can I run the QProcess from the Python environment that I am freezing? So that the users don't have to install anything to run their scripts other than my app.

Right now, after freezing, the QProcess uses the default Python environment installed on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because you always need:

- The interpreter (that is, Python) and
- The dependencies of the libraries (for example, numpy needs some dlls).

What they propose in the another answer is only viable if you have python installed that interprets the script.

Comment: But pyinstaller packages and freezes the python runtime into an executable. My question is how can I access that packaged environment

Comment: @T.J. I understand that you have 2 applications: A script that uses Qt (QProcess) and a second script that is launched through QProcess. So if you don't want both scripts to depend on python, you must convert both scripts to .exe

Comment: so there's no way to re-use the packaged python environment?

Comment: @T.J. Not all python is packaged but only what is necessary, only the dependencies of the .exe

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi,I have a similar problem, can I do it by set QProcessEnvironment?

Answer (score 0):

You can import user script in your app using `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader`

user_script.py

```py
import numpy as np
print("hello from user_script.py")
print(np.zeros(1))
```

app.py

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
def load_user_script(path):
    SourceFileLoader("user_module", path).load_module()
```

to run in separate thread use `QThread`

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, path, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._path = path
    def run(self):
        SourceFileLoader("user_module", self._path).load_module()

worker = Worker(path)
worker.start()
```

Comment: I’m not sure this works for me. I’m running a QProcess Python command. I want to use the Python environment that I package using fbs freeze. What if the user doesn’t have Python installed at all? I still want them to be able to run

Comment: When you freezing you app you essentialy build in python interpreter and packages, so user will have python for sure.

Comment: When I run the user_script.py I am running it through QProcess with command `python` and the absolute path of the script. Can you explain please how importing the user script into my app helps? my goal is to use numpy in the user_script which I already have installed and frozen within my application.

Comment: If you run it with `QProcess` you cannot access frozen packages, but you dont have to run it this way, instead you can import user script into your app, this way all frozen packages will be accessable (using imports) to user.

Comment: How can I run it in a background thread without QProcess? I dont want the script to run within my application

Comment: You can use `QThread` to run it in "background"

Comment: @mugiseyebrows not only importing a user created script in a running app is a **serious** security issue, but it could also result in other problems, starting with a "simple" app freeze, up to a fatal crash. While I can understand the necessity (it *can* be done, and some programs do provide such feature), it is *very* important to not underestimate this aspect.